# How do I close a particular pdf/image/html file in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

When I close a particular /html/image file using the code below then it closes all the /html/image files which are open. Currently I am open the pdf/html/image file using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathOfFile);

I want to close a particular file whose name matches, not all the files.

```
Process[] runingProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < runingProcess.Length; i++)
{

  if (runingProcess[i].MainWindowTitle.Contains(fileName))//runingProcess[i].MainWindowTitle ==string. processName)
  {
    // kill  running process
    runingProcess[i].CloseMainWindow();
  }

}
```

Any suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

[Interapplication Communication API for Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf) is what you need, this supports opening and closing pdf files